# forEach loop behaving strangely with called function values logged at end of the loop instead of during

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise

**EDIT:** currently i think the problem with this is that forEach is not promise aware. https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

I am trying to apply a node javascript translation function (ive put it at the end of the post because it is quite long) to loop over an array of values. However when i loop for some reason i'm only getting certain parts of my looped function to appear after the loop has completed: Allow me to make this more clear:

```
array = [["hello", "hello" ],
         ["my", "my",  ],
         ["name", "name" ],
         ["is", "my" ],
         ["joe", "joe"]]

function process (item,index){
   
const translate = require('@vitalets/google-translate-api');
      
      console.log('loopaction'); //this shows that the loop is executing
    translate(item[0], {to: 'sp'}).then(result => {
    console.log(result.text);
  
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
})


array.forEach(process);   // Applying the function process to the array in a ForEach loop
```

from this i am getting

loopaction
loopaction
loopaction
loopaction
loopaction

hola
mi
nombre
es
joe

So it seems that the forEach loop is completing before the values are being allowed to be  displayed. Which is something i really don't understand since the array values are being translated correctly and then logged out in the correct order. As if they had been stored in the memory for later. And then called at the end of the forEach loop  order.

The translate function looks  like this:

```
function translate(text, opts, gotopts) {
opts = opts || {};
gotopts = gotopts || {};
var e;
[opts.from, opts.to].forEach(function (lang) {
    if (lang && !languages.isSupported(lang)) {
        e = new Error();
        e.code = 400;
        e.message = 'The language \'' + lang + '\' is not supported';
    }
});
if (e) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        reject(e);
    });
}

opts.from = opts.from || 'auto';
opts.to = opts.to || 'en';
opts.tld = opts.tld || 'com';

opts.from = languages.getCode(opts.from);
opts.to = languages.getCode(opts.to);

var url = 'https://translate.google.' + opts.tld;
return got(url, gotopts).then(function (res) {
    var data = {
        'rpcids': 'MkEWBc',
        'f.sid': extract('FdrFJe', res),
        'bl': extract('cfb2h', res),
        'hl': 'en-US',
        'soc-app': 1,
        'soc-platform': 1,
        'soc-device': 1,
        '_reqid': Math.floor(1000 + (Math.random() * 9000)),
        'rt': 'c'
    };

    return data;
}).then(function (data) {
    url = url + '/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute?' + querystring.stringify(data);
    gotopts.body = 'f.req=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify([[['MkEWBc', JSON.stringify([[text, opts.from, opts.to, true], [null]]), null, 'generic']]])) + '&';
    gotopts.headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';

    return got.post(url, gotopts).then(function (res) {
        var json = res.body.slice(6);
        var length = '';

        var result = {
            text: '',
            pronunciation: '',
            from: {
                language: {
                    didYouMean: false,
                    iso: ''
                },
                text: {
                    autoCorrected: false,
                    value: '',
                    didYouMean: false
                }
            },
            raw: ''
        };

        try {
            length = /^\d+/.exec(json)[0];
            json = JSON.parse(json.slice(length.length, parseInt(length, 10) + length.length));
            json = JSON.parse(json[0][2]);
            result.raw = json;
        } catch (e) {
            return result;
        }

        if (json[1][0][0][5] === undefined) {
            // translation not found, could be a hyperlink?
            result.text = json[1][0][0][0];
        } else {
            json[1][0][0][5].forEach(function (obj) {
                if (obj[0]) {
                    result.text += obj[0];
                }
            });
        }
        result.pronunciation = json[1][0][0][1];

        // From language
        if (json[0] && json[0][1] && json[0][1][1]) {
            result.from.language.didYouMean = true;
            result.from.language.iso = json[0][1][1][0];
        } else if (json[1][3] === 'auto') {
            result.from.language.iso = json[2];
        } else {
            result.from.language.iso = json[1][3];
        }

        // Did you mean & autocorrect
        if (json[0] && json[0][1] && json[0][1][0]) {
            var str = json[0][1][0][0][1];

            str = str.replace(/<b>(<i>)?/g, '[');
            str = str.replace(/(<\/i>)?<\/b>/g, ']');

            result.from.text.value = str;

            if (json[0][1][0][2] === 1) {
                result.from.text.autoCorrected = true;
            } else {
                result.from.text.didYouMean = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        err.message += `\nUrl: ${url}`;
        if (err.statusCode !== undefined && err.statusCode !== 200) {
            err.code = 'BAD_REQUEST';
        } else {
            err.code = 'BAD_NETWORK';
        }
        throw err;
    });
});
}
```

I realise there is a promise format and the problem im having may have to do with the asychronisity of the function and how the long the promise is taking to get resolved. I cant seem to figure out why the promise is not resolving or displaying after my forEach function is completely looped yet it seems to be saved correctly and in the correct order. Very odd.

Any ideas about what is it about the function translate()  that is making this happen? Is there anyway i can rewrite my  function process () to make sure that the translate functions resolved promise and the .then() in function process () is fully executed before moving on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you are using promises, so `translate()` will run asynchronously (in the background) while the rest of your code is executing. That is why you go through all the `foreach()` before the translate function returns, and therefore you get that output.

However, there is also a problem using a forEach loop in an async function or a promise block. The callback function is not being awaited. Therefore, the promise chain is broken, resulting in the unexpected behavior.
Don't use forEach loop in a promise or async function. Instead, use a for loop to iterate through the items of the array:

To avoid these problems, change the forEach loop to a For loop and use `async` and `await` like this:

```
async function process (item,index){
    const translate = require('@vitalets/google-translate-api');
    console.log('loopaction'); //this shows that the loop is executing
    await translate(item[0], {to: 'sp'})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.text);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
}

async function main() {
    array = [["hello", "hello" ],
         ["my", "my" ],
         ["name", "name" ],
         ["is", "my" ],
         ["joe", "joe"]]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        await process(array[i], i);
    }
}

main()
```

`await` makes the function wait until the promise is resolved.

***NOTE***: You tried to create a timeout with `object.sleep()`, this doesn't exist in javascript, use `setTimeout()` instead, refer to: [Sleep() in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I upvoted because this seems like the correct direction however im getting the same result unfortunately.

Comment: i will edit the question to include your advice .

Comment: I have edited the answer, try if it works as expected.

Comment: Probably you will get an empty result, because you have to add async and await in the translate function as well. I am going to add it now to the answer.

Comment: Thank you !. I ran your first edit but it ran the same as before. as to next: ideally i was hoping not to edit the translate function although its also just fine if thats what must be done

Comment: Is the translate() result printed out with this edit?

Comment: yes its printed, just in the same way as before, all loops exexuted and then printed out perfectly in the correct order but after .

Comment: i think the problem is: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/ , forEach is not 'promise aware'

Comment: Yes, I've just notice, the problem is with the forEach loop

Comment: You will have to change the forEach loop -> for loop

Comment: All right, the forEach problem is fixed in this solution.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks you so much for helping me understand this.